# Help identifying spider found in central Indiana US

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I noticed this spider outside my garage tonight, and I'm curious if anyone can help identify what type it is.

A few details to help:

I live in central Indiana, United States.
I saw it for the first time at night.
It's body was roughly 3/4 inches (might be slightly bigger).
Each brick in the picture is about 2 1/8 inches. 
It seems to have a black velvet like texture.
It was sitting on a gas pipe that leads into my house. 
It was under a bush.

Sorry the pictures aren't great. Being under a bush and trying to use a flashlight made it a bit harder.
[image: Image of the spider]

[More photographs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FBqg.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a black lace-weaver, or Amaurobius ferox. Based on the size you described it seems as though this one is an adult female. These spiders avoid bright spaces and if they feel cornered they might bite you.

For pictures of it you can look here https://www.arkive.org/black-lace-weaver/amaurobius-ferox/ and for more information you can look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaurobius_ferox